# Continue page execution even JavaScript found an error

Tags: javascript, exception, continue

When found an issue, the javascript is stopped the page loading. What is the way to prevent this? I am working on a buggy web application and I want to load the page fully before doing the testing. In the console, it shows an issue but the site is not loading. how to overcome this?

Comment: `"What is the way to prevent this?"` Fix the error? It is impossible for us to help with the information provided.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript executes line by line, and when an error is reached JavaScript stops execution. It's a natural behavior. You just should to fix these errors. Or you can comment all the lines that cause an error, if it's not breaking the app. JavaScript can continue execution when an error is caught and properly handled by *try...catch* block in your code

Comment: _"It's a natural behavior."_ I wouldn't call a script engine _"natural"_.